# jQuery element show and slide down on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So Im learning jQuery / JavaScript. I believe the title says it all trying to get a div section which is set to `display: none` show whilst slowly sliding down on button click

As per jQuery manual, W3schools and other few places where I've tried to read up, this is what I came up with. Needless to say it doesn't look pretty.

My logic here is that the code should get executed on button click hench I put the onclick event handler to the button element.

```js
function showPackages(){
  $('#submitBtn').on('click', function(){
    $('#showPackages').slideDown('slow', function(){
      $('#showPackages').css('display', 'inline');
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="dispPackages" style="display: none">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help / advice appreciated.

Comment: Remove the function, the onclick handler and just use the code inside the function in a document ready function

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to `bind` **event** handlers separated.

```
function showPackages(){
    $('#submitBtn').on('click', function(){
      $('#showPackages').slideDown('slow', function(){
        $('#showPackages').css('display', 'inline');
      });
    });
}
```

As you writed every time when you click the input it attached a click event handler to your `submitBtn`.

Change it to this:

```
function showPackages(){

}
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(){

});
$('#showPackages').slideDown('slow', function(){
    $('#showPackages').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

But, if you want to trigger the event automatically, use `.trigger()` method.

```
function showPackages(){
    $('#submitBtn').trigger('click');
    $('#showPackages').trigger('slideDown');
}
```

Comment: The ID of the element with `display:none` should also be `showPackages` instead of `dispPackages` I think, not sure though

Comment: @Alexandru thank you for your answer. Problem is the css is not changing to display:inline because I still cant see the div content. DOM throwing no errors though

Comment: @NarenMurali I did change the ID on DIV to `showPackages` im working with the second example

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

show and hide can be done with different effects

- hide() and show()
- fadeIn(), fadeOut() and fadeToggle()
- slideUp(), slideDown() and slideToggle()

*In your case you want slide effect so just use **slideToggle()**

```js
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(){
//$('#dispPackages').slideToggle('slow')   this will set display:block   
$('#dispPackages').slideToggle('slow').css("display","inline-block");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id="submitBtn">clickhere</button>

<div class="panel-group" id="dispPackages" style="display: none">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just a quick question regarding this, where do you change the css to display with your above code...? Just curious

Comment: I didnt get you?  you mean how I am doing show/hide ?

Comment: Yes since the inline style of containg div is set to `display:none` where in the code above do you set it to `display:inline` to show the content...?

Comment: You get what im trying to say?